# SSRS 2008 Bar Graph with 2 Data sets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, bar-chart

Afternoon All,

I am creating a series of graphs and line charts to report data on.

One of the graphs my user requires is a bar graph that essentially holds two values and im not too sure this can be done? Essentially the graph he has drawn has a range from 40 to -40.  He wishes the range from 0 - 40 to report on one value and the range 0 to -40 to hold the other value.

I have already created a stored procedure to pull back the data with the two sets if values for my two meters but cant figure out a way to show this in a bar graph.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards
Bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good workaround solution for you will be to use two graph close to each other.

See example:
[image]

for the lower graph, click on `Y-Axis` and set the propery `Reverse` to `true`